# Git alias fails to push, with errors

Tags: git

I am creating a git alias as follows (broken into lines for readability):

```
git config --global alias.make-release '
! _() { if test "$1" != "2" ; then echo "git make-release TAG_NUMBER DESCRIPTION"; return 1; fi; }; 
_ "$#" 
&& git checkout release 
&& git merge master 
&& git fetch --tags 
&& git tag -a "$1" -m "$2" 
&& git push origin release --tags'
```

This command merges `master` into `release`, creates a new tag from the command line params and pushes it origin/release. It works upto the point of tag creation. When i run, i get this:

```
Switched to branch 'release'
Already up-to-date.
error: src refspec Testing does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Stockopedia/prototype.git'
```

I have 2 issues :

1. The last command `git push origin release --tags` does not work.
   Why?
2. What do the last two lines mean? Why are they happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be better, but I haven't fully tested it - it's formatted for readability, not for shell consumption, you may need to tweak the line breaks and spacing some:

```
git config --global alias.make-release '
! _() { if test "$1" != "2" ;
        then
          echo "git make-release TAG_NUMBER DESCRIPTION"
          return 1
        fi;
        git checkout release &&
        git merge master &&
        git fetch --tags &&
        git tag -a "$1" -m "$2" &&
        git push origin release --tags
}; _'
```

I think the biggest problem is misunderstanding how aliases are expanded. Your posted code results in an expansion that, given `git make-release arg1 arg2` looks to the shell like:

```
_() { if .... }; _ "$#" && git checkout .... && git push origin release --tags arg1 arg2
```

where the expansions of `$#`, `$1` and `$2` are not likely what you expect, and may even be empty - the arguments are not passed to `git tag` as you seem to want. To fix that, the entire thing needs to be inside the function, and the function name is the last thing in the alias, so you get essentially:

```
_() { .... }; _ arg1 arg2
```

Comment: `_() { .... }; _ arg1 arg2` - Brilliant suggestion!

For the posterity, the git docs for aliases are here :https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Aliases_with_arguments